# Knockout click binding after bubbling

Tags: knockout.js, event-bubbling

Is there a way to cause the click to run *after* the event has bubbled?  In the below scenario, clicking the span triggers removeChildNode function which removes the span from dom.  this prevents the span's click from triggering a click on the 'div[data-identifier]' node.  I'd like the event to bubble up and then the function to execute.

```
<div data-identifier>
  <div data-bind="click: removeChildNode">
    <span>Click Me!</span>
  </div>
</div>

removeChildNode = function() { $(arguments[1].target).children()[0].remove(); }

$('body').on("click", 'span', function(event) {
  // use the span to navigate around and do something interesting
  $(event.target).closest('div[data-identifier]').click();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use Knockout, you need to let it control the DOM, and you manipulate your viewmodel. You should have some viewmodel entity that represents the removable child, and your `removeChildNode` function would remove it (or set it into a state that indicates it is removed). As a general rule, jQuery selectors indicate you have failed to model something.

There is no point in having two ways to set up click events. If you are going to use a jQuery click event in one place, you should use jQuery for all your click events and not use Knockout.

That said, by default, Knockout does allow events to bubble. You could put a `setTimeout` around the node remover to give the DOM time to propagate events before you remove the node, if that's what's keeping your outer click from firing. You will have fewer problems of this sort if you leave the DOM entirely to Knockout.

Comment: while i agree that ideally knockout would own everything, it's not an option for me at present.  setTimeout worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap you click bind like so

```
data-bind="click: function(){setTimeout(removeChildNode(),20);return true;}"
```

By setting the timeout you will delay the execution of removeChildNode.

By wrapping your call to a function you can then return immediatly true, which i think tell koJs to bubble the event. So you achieve bubbling and execute removeChild after some delay.

I did not try this on a fiddle, but i think it should work, if you try it let me know how it goes, maybe i should be sure my answers are solid before answering,but i think i'm correct on this one :)

Comment: Returning true tells Knockout not to `preventDefault`. Knockout bubbles events by default.